# math expression returns zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry to ask a dumb question, but this one's got me stumped.

```
SELECT 
81234 / 160000 * 100                    AS Try1,
CAST((81234 / 160000 * 100) AS float)   AS Try2
```

The answer is 50.77125 but both values return zero. What's the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: @mishik You're fiddling with MySQL, not SQL Server

Comment: the answers below are correct.  What's actually happening is that since one or more of your operands is an integer, sql assumes you want an integer answer.  The way that works is that the decimal point is simply dropped off.  So what you end up with is (81234 / 160000) = 0; 0*100 = 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a decimal point.

Something like

```
SELECT 
81234 / 160000 * 100                    AS Try1,
CAST((81234 / 160000 * 100) AS float)   AS Try2,
81234. / 160000. * 100.                    AS Try3
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17633)

From [/ (Divide) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx)

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is
>   an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

Comment: Note: You only need decimal point on one of the division operands. Either 81234. or 160000. Only when both are integer, the result will be integer.

Answer (score 3):

you're implementing a division by int

Try this:

```
SELECT 
cast(81234 as float) / cast(160000 as float) * 100
```

or

```
SELECT 
81234.00 / 160000.00 * 100
```

Comment: You don't have to change the `divisor` to decimal, only the `dividend`.

Comment: Depends, we don't know the nature of the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT 
81234.00 / 160000 * 100                    AS Try1,
CAST((81234.00 / 160000 * 100) AS float)   AS Try2
```

You're dividing a number that is considered an integer. Thus, by adding two decimals it is converted to a decimal number and decimals are displayed.

In your case, the division 81234 / 160000 resulted in a 0, which multiplied by 100 is still 0.

Answer (score 2):

the cause of that is that `81234 / 160000` is an integer division so it returns 0, force it to be float like `81234. / 160000` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer divides.  81234/160000 gives zero.  Multiply by 100 and it's still zero.

Try converting to floats before doing the division.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query like below

```
SELECT 
 81234.00 / 160000 * 100                    AS Try1,
 CAST((81234.00 / 160000 * 100) AS float)   AS Try2
```

** 81234.00 / 160000 return 0.5077125 by manual through sql it will think as Integer Division so it will return the value 0.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the value 81234 is integer and if you devide an integer it will return integer only concerting 81234 in to float will return float

`SELECT 
(CONVERT(FLOAT,81234) / 160000) * 100                    AS Try1,
((CONVERT(FLOAT,81234) / 160000 * 100)   AS Try2`

Thanks 
Ashutosh Arya